# Two javascript codes get in conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, conflict

I recently installed two js to my webpage, but always just one works.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery.carouFredSel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('#foo1').carouFredSel({
                    auto: {
                        pauseOnHover: 'resume',
                        progress: '#timer1'
                    }
                }, {
                    transition: true
                });
            });
        </script>
```

And the other one:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="res/colorbox.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="res/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.fn.colorbox({href:"images/felugro.png", open:true});  
    }, 1500);
});  
</script>
```

But it seems that the two ajax links get in conflinct and if I remove one ajax link, the other works perfectly, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There is no AJAX here.

Both functions are `document.ready()` :

```
$(function() {
```

Equals :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

I'd recommend you to remove one of the jquery inclusions :

this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

and put your code in the same `document.ready` function.

(Better to keep 1.8.3 I think.)

Comment: Actually Colorbox supports AJAX, the Q is pretty confusing